# Angular app in UWP project does not load second page

Tags: c#, angular, uwp

I have an Angular project that I am trying to incorporate into a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application. I have tested the Angular code in my web browser, and all works as expected there. When I try to run the Angular application, that is housed with-in the UWP app bundle, I am unable to navigate to pages.

**Technical Stack**

I have an Angular web application that I have tested in a web browser. it works fine. I run the following command to build the application.

```
ng build --base-href=/Assets/Web
```

I then take the built files, and copy them into my UWP project. The folder structure is below.

```
-- Root
---- Assets
------ Web
-------- assets
-------- index.html
-------- main.js
-------- main.js.map
-------- ect...
```

Basically, the Angular project is put into the /Assets/Web folder within my UWP project.

Then in my MainPage.xaml file I have a WebView with the following code.

```
 <WebView 
    Name="webView"
    Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/Web/index.html"
    NavigationStarting="WebView_NavigationStarting"></WebView>
```

**Problem**

When I run my UWP app I see the initial landing page of my Angular project and all images/styles load correctly. When I click on to the next page in my Angular app, via a `this.router.navigate([RouterLinks.secondPage])` command then the screen just turns white. I see the following in my JavaScript console.

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
secondPage
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "!DOCTYPE html>".
secondPage (1,1)
```

It looks like the routing started to the correct page, but it seems that the rendering never completed.

On initial app load I see a bunch of errors in my VS Output window.

```
'Identity.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (WebView/3.0)'. 
SourceMap ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/runtime.js.map read failed: The URI prefix is not recognized..SourceMap ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/polyfills.js.map read failed: The URI prefix is not recognized..Exception was thrown at line 1145, column 35 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/polyfills.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: 2
SourceMap ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/styles.js.map read failed: The URI prefix is not recognized..SourceMap ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/scripts.js.map read failed: The URI prefix is not recognized..Exception was thrown at line 1323, column 21 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/scripts.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 1341, column 21 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/scripts.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 10757, column 21 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/scripts.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.filter: 'this' is null or undefined
Exception was thrown at line 10757, column 21 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/scripts.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.map: 'this' is null or undefined
```

Then after the router navigation I see the following errors in the Output window.

```
Exception was thrown at line 67843, column 4 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/vendor.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 63600, column 13 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/vendor.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [object Object]
Exception was thrown at line 63658, column 9 in ms-appx-web://d4abdafc-2387-4a97-9c8e-b370601c7288/Assets/Web/vendor.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [object Object]
```

This is when I see the blank screen.

I know this issue has something to do with these errors, but not sure how to fix them. I even tried to put the entire Angular project straight into the root directory of my UWP project, and still had the same issue.

One thing to mention is I did have this as a UWP Web Context application, and during that time everything worked correctly. Unfortunately, I had to move away from that template since I had a need to integrate API calls using the native layer. Right now this is a simple blank UWP project.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the submit input type was causing the form to submit and would actually load the URL from the `router.navigate` command. It is a very strange issue, and seems to only occur in the Edge browser. All other browsers the submit event was prevented internally by Angular.

I fixed the issue by passing the event into the click function via the HTML template, and called the `preventDefault()` function on the event within my custom handler. This stopped the browser from submitting the form and thus sending the browser to a different URL that does not exist. See example below.

In *form.component.html*

```
<input id="submit" role="button" (click)="myEventHandler($event);" value="Submit" type="submit" />
```

In form.component.ts

```
myEventHandler = function (e) {

    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    this.router.navigate(["nextPage"]);
}
```